# my game piece won't move properly and freezes the game

Tags: javascript

I'm using Javascript to make a game and my character is supposed to move a box only when it's touching the box, but it always moves and when my character is on the same y-axis as the right side of of the box the game freezes, even if my character is not touching the right side of the box. I only coded the box to be able to be pushed left so far. I want to make sure that it can move left properly before I move on to making it be able to move elsewhere. My character does not move, instead everything *but* the character moves to make it seem like its moving without having to have different areas and stuff. There is code for other things, but its not used so I can isolate the code for the box. My code is mostly Javascript but does have a little bit of html.

````
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
    <script src="script2.js"></script>



</body>
</html>





var wall
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacle;
var object1;
var objects;
var box;
function startGame() {
  //creation of objects
    wall = new component(30, 100, "black", 300, 200);
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 240, 135);
    myObstacle  = new component(100, 100, "green", 200, 100);    
    myMap = new component(0, 0, "map.jpeg", -100, -100, "image")
    object1 =  new component(30, 30, "gray", 340, 125);
    box = new component(30, 30, "blue", 290, 145);
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);

        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
      window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
      myGameArea.key = false;
    })
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
  collide : function() {
    object1.x += 1;
    object1.y += 1;
  },

  
  boxup : function() {
    box.x -= 1;
      
  }

}




function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    if (type == "image") {
      this.image = new Image();
      this.image.src = color;
    }
    
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (type == "image") {
          ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
                        this.x, 
                        this.y, 
                        this.width, 
                        this.height);
        } else {
        
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;        
    }    
this.crashWith = function(object1) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = object1.x;
    var otherright = object1.x + (object1.width);
    var othertop = object1.y;
    var otherbottom = object1.y + (object1.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
    (mytop > otherbottom) ||
    (myright < otherleft) ||
    (myleft > otherright)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  }




  
this.pushboxleftWith = function(box) {
    
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var boxleft = box.x;
    var boxright = box.x + (box.width);
    var boxtop = box.y;
    var boxbottom = box.y + (box.height);
    var pushboxdown = true;
    var pushboxup = true;
    var pushboxleft = true;
    var pushboxright = true;
   
      if (mybottom < boxtop) {
        pushboxdown = true;
      }
  if (mytop > boxbottom) {
        pushboxup = true;
      }
  if (myright < boxleft) {
        pushboxright = true;
      } 
  if ((myleft > boxright) && (((myBottom <= boxtop) && (myBottom >= boxbottom)) || ((myTop <= boxtop) && (myTop >= boxbottom)))) {
        pushboxleft = false;
      }
      return pushboxleft;
      return pushboxright;
      return pushboxdown;
      return pushboxup;
      
    }

  }


  









    
  


function updateGameArea() {
  if (myGamePiece.crashWith(object1)) {
    myGameArea.collide();
  } else {
    
    if (myGamePiece.pushboxleftWith(box)) {
    myGameArea.boxup();
  } 
   
 
    
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
  myGamePiece.speedY = 0;

  //keyboard controls. work but look ugly. moves everything but the player
  if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37) {myObstacle.x += 2; myMap.x += 2;object1.x+=2; box.x += 2; wall.x += 2;}
  if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39) {myObstacle.x += -2; myMap.x += -2; object1.x+=-2; box.x += -2; wall.x += -2;}
  if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 38) {myObstacle.y += 2; myMap.y += 2; object1.y+=2; box.y += 2; wall.y += 2}
  if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40) {myObstacle.y+=-2; object1.y += -2; myMap.y += -2; box.y += -2; wall.y += -2}

  //other square movement. disabled to isolate code.
    /*
  if (object1.x < myGamePiece.x) {
    object1.x += 1;
  }
  if (object1.x > myGamePiece.x) {
    object1.x += -1;
  }
  if (object1.y < myGamePiece.y) {
    object1.y += 1;
  }
  if (object1.y > myGamePiece.y) {
    object1.y += -1;
  }
*/
  /* object order: the object that is higher on the list
will be on top of objects lower on the list
*/
  myMap.update();

  
  myObstacle.update();
  



myGamePiece.newPos();
myGamePiece.update();
wall.update();
  object1.update();
    box.update();
  //end of list
}
  }```
````

Comment: It's honestly not very clear what you expect from this code. I give you two tips: 1. When you ask on SO, always create a reproducible example, help you and whoever has to answer you. 2. Use the developer tools of your browser, help you to find problems. Specifically, since JS is case senstive, you have a problem with the variables `mytop` and `mybottom` that once you use them with lowercase and other times with uppercase (`myBottom`). [Here is a (working?) example](https://jsfiddle.net/7qLy8jmg/) with a low frame rate (100ms).

Answer (score 1):

> My game piece won't move properly and freezes the game

As Baro pointed out, JavaScript variables are case-sensitive, meaning `mybottom` and `myBottom` are completely different variables. So when you tried to access `myBottom`, having only set `mybottom`, you got an error. Your game froze because you were running that code in your set interval, every 20 milliseconds.

Here is a working version of your code that you can play around with. I have refactored it a little:

```js
let objects;
let wall = new component(30, 100, "black", 300, 200);
let myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 240, 135);
let myObstacle = new component(100, 100, "green", 200, 100);
let myMap = new component(0, 0, "orange", -100, -100)
let object1 = new component(30, 30, "gray", 340, 125);
let box = new component(30, 30, "blue", 290, 145);

const myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.querySelector("#game-area"),
  start: function() {
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      myGameArea.key = false;
    })
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  },
  collide: function() {
    object1.x += 1;
    object1.y += 1;
  },
  boxup: function() {
    box.x -= 1;
  }
}
myGameArea.start();

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
  this.newPos = function() {
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY;
  }
  this.crashWith = function(object1) {
    let myleft = this.x;
    let myright = this.x + (this.width);
    let mytop = this.y;
    let mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    let otherleft = object1.x;
    let otherright = object1.x + (object1.width);
    let othertop = object1.y;
    let otherbottom = object1.y + (object1.height);
    let crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
      (mytop > otherbottom) ||
      (myright < otherleft) ||
      (myleft > otherright)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  }

  this.pushboxleftWith = function(box) {
    let myleft = this.x;
    let myright = this.x + (this.width);
    let mytop = this.y;
    let mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    let boxleft = box.x;
    let boxright = box.x + (box.width);
    let boxtop = box.y;
    let boxbottom = box.y + (box.height);
    let pushboxdown = true;
    let pushboxup = true;
    let pushboxleft = true;
    let pushboxright = true;

    if (mybottom < boxtop) pushboxdown = true;
    if (mytop > boxbottom) pushboxup = true;
    if (myright < boxleft) pushboxright = true;

    if ((myleft > boxright) && (((mybottom <= boxtop) && (mybottom >= boxbottom)) || ((mytop <= boxtop) && (mytop >= boxbottom)))) {
      pushboxleft = false;
    }
    return pushboxleft;
    return pushboxright;
    return pushboxdown;
    return pushboxup;
  }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  if (myGamePiece.crashWith(object1)) {
    myGameArea.collide();
  } else {
    if (myGamePiece.pushboxleftWith(box)) {
      myGameArea.boxup();
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;

    //keyboard controls. moves everything but the player
    if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37) {
      myObstacle.x += 2;
      myMap.x += 2;
      object1.x += 2;
      box.x += 2;
      wall.x += 2;
    }
    if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39) {
      myObstacle.x += -2;
      myMap.x += -2;
      object1.x += -2;
      box.x += -2;
      wall.x += -2;
    }
    if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 38) {
      myObstacle.y += 2;
      myMap.y += 2;
      object1.y += 2;
      box.y += 2;
      wall.y += 2
    }
    if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40) {
      myObstacle.y += -2;
      object1.y += -2;
      myMap.y += -2;
      box.y += -2;
      wall.y += -2
    }
    myMap.update();
    myObstacle.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
    wall.update();
    object1.update();
    box.update();
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="script2.js" type="module"></script>
  <canvas id="game-area" width="480" height="270"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks! this is great. I use repl.it and my framerate is fine there.